# AppFabric Cache Cluster not detecting a node has failed in a timely fashion

Tags: caching, appfabric

### Setup:

We're using AppFabric 1.1 on Windows 2008 Enterprise Edition VMs.

We setup a cluster with three nodes using SQL server for cluster configuration and also using offloading so SQL server is supposed to do the cluster management by making sure to create the cluster with: `New-AFCacheCluster -Offloading true`. We then add the three nodes and start the cluster up. All is good.

We then setup a single cache instance, call it "Test", with HA using the `-Secondaries 1` option.

### Test Scenario:

We then use a test app to put some test data into the cache and access that data and everything is working great. So then we go to the VM host and down the NIC for one of the nodes in the cluster to simulate that node's failure.

### Results:

As soon as the NIC is disabled on the one node, when we go to read from the cache we get timeouts instead of a clean failover.

If we go run `Get-AFCacheHostStatus` on either of the other two hosts that are still up, the first time after the NIC is disabled, this call will take a very long time to return the status of the hosts. Once it finally does return status, it shows the node on which we yanked the NIC as being in `UNKNOWN` status. Subsequent calls to Get-AFCacheHostStatus will return quickly, but always showing the error message that the one node is unreachable and shows it in the `UNKNOWN` status.

Ok, so AF itself detects that node is in `UNKNOWN` status, but the test app is still getting timeouts at this point. Some minutes later, somewhere btwn 5-10mins, the app will eventually start working again with only the two nodes we have left.

---

Sooo, what's going on here? Are we configuring something incorrectly? Why is the cluster taking so long to recover from this basic kind of failure?